# Upload Data URI image to Facebook using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am working on a html5 project. in here, i got a snap-shot of canvas and it is in Data Uri format. now i want to upload this data uri image to facebook as png image file. I was tried several method. But unfortunately i was unable to find a correct way to do this. Please help me, thank you

Comment: Show us some code that you've tried so that we mat assist you better

Answer (score 0):

Need to converto to blob and post as formdata, cause facebook api sucks. It doesn wok in IE 9 but it does in modern browsers. Hope it helps.

```
function dataURLToBlob(dataURL) {
var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';

if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
    var parts = dataURL.split(',');
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = parts[1];

    return new Blob([raw], {
        type: contentType
    });
}

var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
var raw = base64.decode(parts[1]); //window.atob(parts[1]);
var rawLength = raw.length;


var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
    uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}

return new Blob([uInt8Array], {
    type: contentType
});
```

};

Comment: For a complete example, see here: http://gorigins.com/posting-a-canvas-image-to-facebook-and-twitter/